# Can "obsess over" have a positive connotation?

Tags: verbs, connotation

I would like to use the verb "obsess over" in this sentence: "Being interested in classical architecture I have always obsessed over Italy."

Does this verb have a positive connotation or does it sound like my obsession over Italy is a negative thing?

Comment: It comes across as having a positive connotation, but honestly phrased thusly it doesn't sound idiomatic. You 'obsess over' things you have control over, and I don't think that bunga-bunga hosts are known for their enduring love of classical architecture.

Comment: Thank you. Would you be so kind to suggest a better idiom?

Comment: With your given example, I'd venture that 'being interested in classical architecture, I've always been obsessed by Italy', or '…I've always been obsessed with Italy' sounds more natural. I'd also wait and see whether anybody else agrees with me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not necessarily have a negative connotation, depending on context. I am not sure it would ever have an actual positive connotation, but it could certainly be a neutral one.